# Converting PHP contact form to AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, twilio

I currently am using the sms service twilio to send a message to users with details. The form submits and delivers when submitted using action and post method whilst submitting. I would like to change this to an AJAX submitted form. Any ideas please? I have included some code below as of how it currently works:

**** Contact form ****

```
<form action="sendsms.php" method="post" id="sms">
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Sam"/>
     <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" value="0000000000"/>
     <textarea name="message" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"> Test Message</textarea>
        <input type='submit' value='submit'/>
    </form>
```

**** PHP ****

```
<?php
    if($_POST)
    {

        require "Services/Twilio.php";


        $AccountSid = "ACaa1c********";
        $AuthToken = "ae6c269********";


        $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

        $from = '+44**********';
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];

        // Send a new outgoing SMS */
        $body = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'].$name );
        $client->account->sms_messages->create($from, $phone, $body );
        echo "Sent message to $name";
    }
?>
```

**** AJAX ****

```
$('#sms').submit(function(event) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    event.preventDefault();
    //get input field values
    var user_name       = $('input[name=name]').val(); 
    var user_phone      = $('input[name=phone]').val();
    var user_message    = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

    var proceed = true;

    if(proceed) 
               {
                 //data to be sent to server
                 post_data = {'userName':user_name, 'userPhone':user_phone, 'userMessage':user_message};

                 //Ajax post data to server
                 $.post('sendsms.php', post_data, function(data){  

                     alert(data);


                        }).fail(function(err) {  //load any error data
                            $("body").hide().html('<div class="error">'+err.statusText+'</div>').slideDown();
                        });
                    }          
                    return true;
                });
```

Comment: Nothing on the form or the PHP has to change, all you need to do is add the AJAX component between them. There are *truckloads* of AJAX tutorials available on the web.

Comment: Hi Jay, I have tried one AJAX tut so far and I keep getting a failed message. Can I ask If I were creating variables for the $_POST for each value does the variable need to be the same name in the AJAX script as it does in the php script?

Comment: Post the AJAX that you tried here @SamCrowe. Also, open your browser's console when testing to see what is being sent and received.

Comment: I have updated the original post Jay, Thanks itachi, useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of jquery to get the action and data from the form directly, with `attr('action')` and `serialize()`:

```
 $(function(){
    $('#sms').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data){
            console.log(data); //alert(data);
        }).fail(function(err){
            console.log(err); //alert(err);
        });
    });
});
```

As noted, alert is a poor method of debugging. 
All modern browsers have a javascript console (Ctrl + Shift + J in google chrome, or rightclick > inspect element to bring up full dev tools).
`console.log()` will send your data to the console. Other javascript errors will also show.

Comment: Well done @Steve but please don't use `alert()` for troubleshooting. [Use `console.log()` instead](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/).

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, i always do, but as the OP has used alert, i thought it better to use something he was familiar with. I hindsite, the answer would be better if it mentions this - will update

Answer (score 2):

```
 $(function(){
                $('#sms').submit(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var d = $(this).serialize();

                    $.ajax({
                        type        :       'post',
                        url         :       'sendsms.php',
                        data        :       d
                    }).done(function(data){
                       alert('done');
                    }).fail(function(x,y,z){
                        alert('error');
                    });

                });
            });
```

its that easy.